# Installing Fluent Security Pre release nuget package

Tags: fluent-security

I've tried to install Fluent Security Pre release package using the below command.

**Install-Package FluentSecurity -Pre**

When I've tried the above command from VS 2010, getting the error below.

PM> Install-Package FluentSecurity -Pre
Install-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Pre'.
At line:1 char:36
+ Install-Package FluentSecurity -Pre <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Install-Package], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Any Thoughts!!!

http://nuget.org/packages/FluentSecurity

Thanks,
-Naren

Answer (score 2):

Please try :

```
Install-Package FluentSecurity -IncludePrerelease
```

Comment: Getting the below error. PM> Install-Package FluentSecurity -IncludePrerelease
Install-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'IncludePrerelease'.
At line:1 char:50
+ Install-Package FluentSecurity -IncludePrerelease <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Install-Package], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Which version of NuGet do you currently have ?
Support for -IncludePrerelease came with NuGet 1.6.